# Use DAMP datatypes as Macro Parameters in Umbraco

Tags: macros, umbraco

I'm just starting to look at using the DAMP media picker within Umbraco. I'd like to be able to create a custom Macro that can be used in the Editor. Within that Macro I'd like users to be able to pick one or more Media items (i.e. a set of images for an Image Gallery).

The DAMP Media Pickers let me do exactly this, be the relevant DataTypes only seem to be available as Generic Properties of Document Types.

Is there a way to use the DAMP media Pickers from within as Custom Macro Parameters.

I've searched around and can find very little on what would be a very useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

From reading some of the DAMP source code (http://damp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b3b45c70ce29#DAMP.RazorModel/DAMP_Item.cs) it looks like the DAMP node picker will be stored just like a ucomponents multinodepicker.

If so then DAMP pickers (like multinodepickers) should be stored as XML - and can then be used as a macro parameter (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ucomponents/questionssuggestions/19682-Can-I-pass-a-MultiNode-as-Parameter-to-Macro)

Alternatively would a propertyTypePickerMultiple work (http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/8135-Looping-through-all-values-of-a-propertyTypePickerMultiple-in-XSLT)

Comment: Thanks for that, some interesting reading. However the DAMP datatypes don't seem to be available when configuring Macro Parameters. Any ideas on how to overcome this?